# HTML Ordered List with "skip to" tag

Tags: html, html-lists

I have an ordered list.
On step 3, I need to tell the user that if the groundhog sees his shadow then skip to step 5.

Is there markup I can use in step 3 to reference the number of the other item?

**Some pseudo-markup:**

```
<ol>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three, if sees shadow skip to <shownumberfor="itemofinterest"/></li>
<li>Four</li>
<li id="itemofinterest">Five</li>
</ol>
```

*Edit for clarification:*

The number "5" should show up in the content of item 3.
If "Five" moves up or down in the list, I want the number to move to point to the new number.

*More edit*

Changed item name to avoid confusion. It could move.

Comment: Do you mean that in step 3 will show a button that when you click on it you will "jump" to step 5?

Comment: Optional. I did not think of that as my initial requirement, no. Merely display the correct [assigned] number would be sufficient.

Comment: Tell me if am I write: You want that instead  <shownumberfor="itemofinterest"/>` will show up "5" and if from some reason the `<li id="itemofinterest">Five</li>` will replace his place, to be a second, for example, the `shownumberfor` will show "2".

Comment: Yes. The number displayed would change if the item moves in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend this solution, because I think that if you change the content of the html, change all of it. Unless this question it's just a part of the picture, and this list also generating dynamically with JavaScript.

```js
$('#itemofinterest-pointer').html(function(){
  return $('li').index($('#itemofinterest')) + 1 /* because the "index" function return the index in base 0 */;
});

/* If you use this code multiple times in your code, wrap this with a function and call it when you need. Don't duplicate the code */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three, if sees shadow skip to <span id="itemofinterest-pointer"></span><!--<shownumberfor="itemofinterest"/></li>-->
  <li>Four</li>
  <li id="itemofinterest">Five</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I agree. This satisfies the question requirements but is overly complex for my use case. I had been hoping for an easy-to-use HTML tag. Many thanks.